# LINQ WHERE DATE Issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Anyone point out the issue?
Keep getting "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

```
public IEnumerable<Appointment> FindAllAppointmentsWithReminders()
{
    DateTime reminderDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
    IEnumerable<Appointment> apps = RepositorySet    
        .OfType<Appointment>()
        .Include("Client")
        .Where(c => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Client.Reminder.Date) == reminderDate.Date 
                        && reminderDate.Date > EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.StartTime.Date));

    return apps;
}
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the `.Date` from your method but this:

```
DateTime reminderDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
```

EntityFramework doesn't support the `.Date` property of `Datetime`. For this reason there is the pseudo-function `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`, and for the `reminderDate` you already remove the time in the `DateTime reminderDate = DateTime.Today.Date`.

```
public IEnumerable<Appointment> FindAllAppointmentsWithReminders()
{
    DateTime reminderDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
    IEnumerable<Appointment> apps = RepositorySet    
        .OfType<Appointment>()
        .Include("Client")
        .Where(c => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Client.Reminder) == reminderDate 
                        && reminderDate > EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.StartTime));

    return apps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public IEnumerable<Appointment> FindAllAppointmentsWithReminders()
{
    DateTime reminderDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
**DateTime NewDate =reminderDate.Date;**
    IEnumerable<Appointment> apps = RepositorySet    
        .OfType<Appointment>()
        .Include("Client")
        .Where(c => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Client.Reminder.Date) == **NewDate** 
                        && reminderDate.Date > EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.StartTime.Date));

    return apps;
}
```